# Getting the value of selected item in Dropdown react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to get the value of selected item in Dropdown. I uses react-bootstrap. I tried placing `onSelect={(e) => console.log(e)}` at `<Dropdown>`, `<Dropdown.Menu>` and `<Dropdown.Item>` but on selecting one country all of above gives me null. 
Dropdown and items are rendered correctly.
please help.

```
return (
    <div>
        <FormGroup className={styles.formControl}>
            <Dropdown >
                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                    Select a Country
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu onSelect={(e) => console.log(e) } className={styles.dropdown_menu}>
                    {countries.map((country,i) => <Dropdown.Item key={i}>{country}</Dropdown.Item> )}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
        </FormGroup>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
return (
    <div>
        <FormGroup className={styles.formControl}>
            <Dropdown >
                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                    {selectedItem?selectedItem:"Select a country"}
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu className={styles.dropdown_menu}>
                    {countries.map((country, i) => <Dropdown.Item onSelect={()=>setSelectedItem(country)} key={i}>{country}</Dropdown.Item> )}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
        </FormGroup>
    </div>
)
```

I hope `onSelect` is the correct handler for the component. Just cross verify that. This should work I suppose.

`useState(null)` can also be `useState(props.value)` in case you're passing down something from parent. That's up to you.